# Queing independent Observables

Tags: java, rx-java

Is it possible to queue multiple observables so that they're executed after eachother, without they are knowing eachother?

Let's say I have 3 different Observables in 3 different classes and/or threads. All of them are representing a different request. The order of when they will be executed, is dependent on which observable has the first subscriber (which we don't know)

What I want is, that they are executed after eachother in some kind of queue and if some 4th observable is joining the queue, this should be added to the queue and executed after the 3rd one.

is that possible with some ootb rx tools?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not fully understanding your question, but can you explain why one of the various [combining methods](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining) (such as `Observable.merge()` or `Observable.combineLatest()`) is inadequate to your needs?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question, you want to build a `Observable` of `Observable`. Then execute Observable in order using `concatMap`

```
Observable<Observable<Result>> tasks = ... //build your Observable of Observable

tasks.concatMap(obs -> obs)
     .subscribe(resultOfNestedObservable -> /** getting result of Observable **/);
```

To test this idea, you try with a `Subject`.

```
 Subject<Observable<Observable<Result>> source = PublishSubject.create(); 
 Observable<Observable<Result>> tasks = source;

 /*...*/
 source.onNext(observable1);
 source.onNext(observable2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have independent observables and independent subscribers but you still want to make sure only one observable is 'executing'. This can be achieved via a custom scheduler:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, r -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t;
});
Scheduler singleThread = Schedulers.from(exec);

Observable o1 = someObservable.subscribeOn(singleThread);
Observable o2 = someObservable.subscribeOn(singleThread);
Observable o3 = someObservable.subscribeOn(singleThread);

o2.subscribe();
o1.subscribe();
o3.subscribe();
```

The ExecutorService has its queue and whoever subscribes first, the others will stay in its queue until the previous one has finished.

Comment: I'll try that, this sounds convincing... I'll keep you updated

Comment: There's a typo...Exectutors should be Executors :)   ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });